# Upgrading old Mac with SMART issues

Tags: terminal, recovery, bootable-disk

I have an older MacBook Pro running 10.9 Mavericks with SMART warnings on the drive. (I understand this means it will eventually fail but I’ve been using this MacBook just fine for the last 5 years and am just having issues due to compatibility of old programs and am looking to update). I have a copy of a 10.12 Sierra bootable install on a flash drive and am following the steps laid out by @featherbelly in the following post:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/457698/494447

The issue I’m having is right at the end when running the startosinstall command from terminal using recovery mode. In the original post, the user specifies a ‘--volume …’ (double dash) argument to install High Sierra on the newly wiped Macintosh HD. However, the startosinstall command for Sierra doesn’t accept the ‘--volume’ argument. Any idea how to make sure I install Sierra on my Macintosh HD and don’t mess anything up? (I was successfully able to add the ‘--application path’ argument but I’m not sure where Sierra would be installed…)

Comment: It appears you’re using a double dash with a space between them.  It should be just a double dash. Example  single: `- volume` and double: `— volume`.  The look similar but the second is definitely “longer”

Comment: Sorry, the space was just to highlight that I was using a double vs single dash. I can edit/clarify the question.

Comment: Just make a small note somewhere that you’re using the double dash